# rotation not working after edge loop select?

Tags: shortcut

Not sure if I am doing something wrong... but...

I have my user prefs configured to use the left mouse button (I prefer that) instead of right mouse button...

If I do an edge loop select (ctrl+shift+alt+ left mouse button) - I can select fine, but now I can't seem to get back into normal rotation mode... (i.e., just pressing shift+alt and dragging left or right, etc) without closing the blender file and re-opening it...

Is there some kind of hotkey I can use to get back into normal rotation/scaling/etc mode?

Thanks!

Comment: Umm I don't think that's how you select edgeloops, you need to press Alt+Left mouse button.

Comment: okay - but how do i get back into normal rotation mode?

Comment: Rotation mode ? Press the R key to rotate, S to scale and G to move.

Comment: that's not what i mean. I mean like before I could move about the viewport (i.e., hold down the alt key while pressing the mouse button to move left/righ/etc) - but after I do an edge loop select it almost seems to 'lock' things up, and it no longer works... any ideas on how to fix that? thanks